# Save as dialog with IE only opens after writer is closed

Tags: java, internet-explorer, servlets, download

With Firefox, download dialog instantly opens when user click on the download link, but I have trouble getting IE to display the Save As dialog before close() gets called on a Writer.

I can't have the initial file to download size since it is generated on the fly.

```
ServletOutputStream os = null;
Writer writer = null;

try {
    os = response.getOutputStream(); // response is from an input param HttpServletResponse
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
    response.setContentType("text/csv; charset=windows-1252");
    writer = new OutputStreamWriter(os, Util.WINDOWS1252);
    writer.write("\u0000"); // flush() will be effective only if there is something in the buffer, this works with firefox, download dialog opens, but with not with IE
    writer.flush(); // forces to open the download popup instantly
    fooManager.processCSV(some params...,  writer); // generated on the fly and written in writer direclty
 } catch (IOException e) {
    logger.debug("csv: IOException ", e);
 } finally {
    if (writer != null) {
    try {
          writer.close(); // now IE will finally open download dialog...
    } catch (IOException e) {
          // ignore
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: 1> Verify in Fiddler that your response is actually streaming. 2> Consider using a bogus MIME type (e.g. application/force-download) to avoid interference from any Excel MIME Filters installed on the machine.

Comment: None works with IE. Chrome, Firefox are working fine with other MIME types. I tried setting response.setContentLength(someRandomLenght) and IE opens the download instantly now. It seems IE needs a file size to display the dialog, otherwise it displays only after the file is downloaded. The problem is, the csv is generated dynamically, so I can't have the file lenght. (I'm running Tomcat 7.0.42 btw)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the filename:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FILENAME
```

And, to force open *Save As* dialog, add:

```
Content-Type: application/force-download
```

Or:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Comment: I tried it with a filename and it is not working. Otherwise, with no filename, the filename is taken from the download URL.

Comment: You are right. The name is like the url after the last slash. Depending on the browser, this will try to open the file automatically. In such cases, you should send a generic MIME for avoid this, like the mp3's in Google Chrome.